# Spree redirect after login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

Spree 2.3 with spree_auth_devise, Rails 4.0

I am trying to redirect users after sign in based on their role. The best solution would be to modify a path, a la Devise, in an initializer, but these don't seem to exist for Spree. The next best solution would be to create a decorator on the sessions controller, but I can't find this controller, nor can I access it when I attempt to follow the information from `rake routes`

How can I redirect users to a new location after login, in a Spree app, based on their role?

**UPDATE**
Overwriting the `after_sign_in_path_for(resource)` method results in the method being triggered, but still rerouting to the `admin_path`.

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    byebug # this is triggered
    root_path
  end
end

### OR ####

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    byebug # this is triggered
    if spree_current_user.has_spree_role?("admin")
      admin_path
    elsif spree_current_user.has_spree_role?("designer")
      new_designers_spree_variant_path
    else
      root_path
    end
  end
end
```

My attempts are being documented here:
https://gist.github.com/asteel1981/0f258260974f4d748fb5

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using `spree_auth_devise` gem?

Comment: Yes. gem 'spree_auth_devise', :git => 'https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise.git', :branch => '2-3-stable'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to @mvidaurre for spending some time with me drilling down into this.

The issue is that spree_auth_devise has a second method that attempts to reroute to the last page attempted, meaning I needed to modify not only the after_sign_in_path_for method, but the Spree method redirect_back_or_default(default).

Additionally, because my user signs in through the admin/sign_in route, I needed to access the Spree::Admin::UserSessionsController instead of simply the Spree::UserSessionsController.

My early solution looks like this:

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if spree_current_user.has_spree_role?("admin")
      admin_path
    elsif spree_current_user.has_spree_role?("designer")
      '/designers/spree_variants/new' #rails helper gives the wrong path, not sure why
    else
      root_path
    end
  end
end

# app/controllers/spree/admin/user_sessions_controller.rb
Spree::Admin::UserSessionsController.class_eval do
  def redirect_back_or_default(default)
    if spree_current_user && spree_current_user.has_spree_role?("admin")
      redirect_to(session["spree_user_return_to"] || default)
      session["spree_user_return_to"] = nil
    else
      redirect_to(default)
    end
  end
end
```

The relevant spree source code is here:
https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise/blob/8cb2d325b2c1da02cbe137404d8dda89cc1613a2/lib/controllers/backend/spree/admin/user_sessions_controller.rb

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answer in the comments. `spree_auth_devise` defines the [`Spree::UserSessionsController`](https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise/blob/2-3-stable/lib/controllers/frontend/spree/user_sessions_controller.rb) you can decorate the controller and use the method described in: [How To: redirect to a specific page on successful sign in](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in)

You can implement your custom method for:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  current_user_path
end
```

Maybe something like this:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  if spree_current_user.has_spree_role?("designer")
    root_path
  elsif spree_current_user.has_spree_role?("admin")
    admin_path
  else
    root_path
  end
end
```

Comment: Initial reports aren't encouraging. Decorating the Spree::UserSessionsController with a method overwrite isn't working, nor is simply trying to overwrite the method in ApplicationController.

Comment: Could you put a gist with the code? To look about that. Thanks

Comment: Yep. Gist link just added to question: https://gist.github.com/asteel1981/0f258260974f4d748fb5

Comment: Only to be sure in the Attempt #2 could you write `puts spree_current_user.roles` after `def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)` and check the console output

Comment: When I run spree_current_user.spree_roles, the correct roles are returned. spree_current_user.has_spree_role? also works as expected.

Comment: Ok. That is inside the method `after_sign_in_path_for(resource)`? Right? For your test, what is the `spree_current_user.spree_roles`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58897/discussion-between-steel-and-mvidaurre).

Answer (score 0):

Spree documentation seems to cover this, check out:

http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/authentication.html

It seems to be a good starting point for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes, I've read all that. It's not very helpful for my question.

Comment: FYI, its https://guides.spreecommerce.org/developer/authentication.html now.  !!! GUIDES.SPREECOMMERCE.ORG !!!